# Unity - UI button not triggering custom script function

Tags: unity, gui

I have created simple movement buttons in my game. They should trigger functions of the player's scripts, but I can't link the button to the player object/script canonically from the inspector 'cause the player is created at runtime. 
So I created a custom script attached to the buttons:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections; 

public class ActionButton : MonoBehaviour {

    private Button btn;

    void Start()
    {
        btn = GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TriggerFoo);
    }

    public void TriggerFoo()
    {
        Debug.Log("Btn triggered!!!!");
    }       
}
```

Haven't implemented yet the behavior I want to achieve with it, but even at this point the button doesn't print the string on console.

Here is how the button is set up in the inspector:

[image]

[image]

I am missing something very obvious here....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What your missing is an `EventSystem` object.

Your button is passing an `OnClick` event when you click on it; but without an `EventSystem` to manage your events, this can have *seemingly* unpredictable results. The `EventSystem` is its own component, and it does not appear to matter where you place it in your hierarchy, just as long as you only have one of them.

I personally had a very similar issue while testing an android prototype game I had made. It took me several months to figure it out, and even than, it wasn't me that figured it out - [I also had to ask about it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/127890/why-does-unity-require-an-eventsystem-component-for-input-during-a-play-test-wh), here on GameDev. While someone was able to point out my initial issue through comments, I am still quite unclear on the overarching issue that had me confused; it appears (or at least, in my case) that input *may* work *without* an `EventSystem` in an actual build. *Assume it won't, and ensure you always include one*. I keep one on my main camera, and have been able to successfully test your code with it.

#### If your using the `CrossPlatformInput` package, you also need to ensure you have matching axis in your `InputManager`.

Since you have not mentioned it, I assume you are *not* using the Unity package `CrossPlatformInput`. Just in case you are, buttons still won't work if you do not have corresponding axis set in your `InputManager`.

For `CrossPlatformInput` to work, it needs to interact with four separate axis in your `InputManager`: Vertical, Horizontal, Submit and Cancel. If you do not have these axis, fatal errors will block your `UI` from handling input. *Simply having these axis does not suitably set them up for `CrossPlatformInput`*, but having them there allows your other input to work as intended.

[image: The <code>InputManager</code>, with the four required axis registered.]

Comment: Thanks  @Timelord64, that was definitely it...! I didn't consider the Event System at all and I though one was automatically generated when creating a UI button. I have no idea why I had not one in my project. Anyway with this solution my buttons are now working. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Click the + thing right under onclick. Now, choose the object "still" (the button). Now, simply find the script then function. In your setup, the button is only storing the script, and the button component isn't actually using it.

Comment: this makes some sense, but I tried your suggestion and still nothing on console...

Comment: That is exactly how you'd use a button set up. You need to try having it activate a sprite instead, since you can guerrantee whether  it'll work. Also, with the console, click the text message box on the console bcause it may be trying to display it, but the console is hiding it.

Comment: Everything else is printing correctly to the console. The script should be able to do something basic as Debug.Log....

Comment: Is the button calling the TriggerFoo function? Also, get rid of the code in Start. It's pointless. Also may be messing up the script

Comment: Have you gotten it fixed, @Uknowho?

Comment: The "Start" code is not initially pointless; it is the scripting method of physically providing the references, as you describe above. If this was an issue of missing the reference, sure, it might help to physically do it yourself. However, asker has confirmed the script is on the same object as the button, so we know that there should be no problem with a simple `GetComponent<Button>()`.

Comment: It's true. Adding a reference to the button itself in the inspector as @The MattBat999 says it's not useful in this case....